# passing argument makes pointer from integer without a cast / expected ‘double *’ but argument is of type ‘int’

Tags: c

I'm very new to C and I'm getting errors in my C program assignment. I'm generating a 4x4 Hilbert matrix and then finding it's determinant via Cramer's Rule. But I get the following errors on my code for both arguments in my function 'main':

```
In function ‘main’:
passing argument 1 of ‘determinant’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  printf("\nThe determinant using Cramer’s Rule is:\%lf\n", determinant(n,H));
  ^
note: expected ‘double *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
double determinant(double * matrix, int n){
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void Hilbert(int n, double H[n][n]) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            H[i][j] = (double)1.0 / ((i + 1) + (j + 1) - 1.0);
        }
    }
}

void printMatrix(int n, double matrix[n][n]) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%lf\t", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

double determinant(double * matrix, int n) {
    if (1 >= n) return matrix[0];
    double *subMatrix = (double*)malloc((n - 1)*(n - 1) * sizeof(double));
    double result = 0.0;
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < i; k++)
                subMatrix[j*(n - 1) + k] = matrix[(j + 1)*n + k];
            for (k = i + 1; k < n; k++)
                subMatrix[j*(n - 1) + (k - 1)] = matrix[(j + 1)*n + k];
        }
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            result += matrix[0 * n + i] * determinant(subMatrix, n - 1);
        else
            result -= matrix[0 * n + i] * determinant(subMatrix, n - 1);
    }
    free(subMatrix);
    return result;
}

int main() {
    int i, j;
    int n = 4;
    double H[n][n];
    Hilbert(n, H);
    printf("\nThe Hilbert matrix is:\n");
    printMatrix(n, H);
    printf("\nThe determinant using Cramer’s Rule is: \%lf\n", determinant(n, H));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just swap parameters of `determinant` in your `printf` call like this:

```
determinant(H,n)
```

And to suppress warnings you may also need to refer to the first row instead of the whole matrix:

```
determinant(H[0],n)
```

Comment: Sadly, that didn't work. I get a similar error now.

In function ‘main’:
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘determinant’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  printf("\nThe determinant using Cramer’s Rule is:\%lf\n", determinant(H,n));
  ^
note: expected ‘double *’ but argument is of type ‘double (*)[(sizetype)(n)]’
 double determinant(double * matrix, int n){

Comment: @meten: It's the correct solution with `H[0]` (or `&H[0][0]`). Have you tried that?